# How to create a uninstall command for a Windows-based application in the Application Folder

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can anyone explain to me how to create a uninstall command for a Windows-based application in the Application Folder when creating a new setup project in visual studio 2008.

I've found info on the net but nothing helping me so far. If you could supply me with links or instructions it would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio.NET:

- File > Add Project > New Project > Setup & Deployment Project > Setup Project
  (Enter name and location)
- Add (right-click in Application Folder > Add > Project Output):

  - Primary Output
- If an error occurs about files that should be excluded > In Solution Explorer select your Setup project > Exclude those files (right-click > exclude)
- Build > Build ’name project’

In Windows:

- Create an Uninstall.bat file containing:
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\MsiExec.exe /I{productcode}

  (Path depends of your Windows version, check where your system32 folder is located)

  (You’ll find the productcode in Visual Studio.NET > Tab Properties in the setup project you’ve just created)
- Open the setup project in Visual Studio.NET if you closed it
- Add (right-click in Application Folder):

  - Add > Project Output > File > Uninstall.bat
  - Create New Shortcut > Application Folder > Primary Output (enter a name)
  - Create New Shortcut > Application Folder > Uninstall.bat (enter a name)
  - Add > File > add .ico files you want to use for the shortcuts
- Shortcuts properties > ‘icon’ property (use the icons you’ve just added)
- Move the shortcuts to User’s Desktop/User’s Programs Menu (you can also create subfolders)
- Build > Rebuild ’name project’

The setup is ready now. You can install via Setup.exe (default it’s located under the folder ‘Debug’, you can change it in Visual Studio.NET - right-click your setup project > properties > Output file name). The shortcuts will be added automatically in the coresponding folders (desktop/start menu).

You can uninstall the program via Uninstall.bat (or via shortcut naar Uninstall.bat)

Comment: Hi, I'm struggling to find the productcode in visual studio 2008. can you be a bit more specific as to where i can find it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The command line for uninstalling using msiexec :

> msiexec /uninstall {GUID}

{GUID} is the Product Code of the setup package and you can find that in your Setup Project Properties. 
The uninstall program can be as simple as a bacth with that command or maybe a separate application, executing the command and performing addional custom cleaning.

L.E. Also, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024(VS.85).aspx) is Microsoft's online documentation for msiexec.

L.E. Good [article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/06/29/add-an-uninstall-shortcut-to-setup-project.aspx) giving code snippet for creating a C# application that performs the uninstall

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier is to just add an uninstall shortcut with arguments directly to the setup project instead of creating a batch file or adding code to the main() sub or start form.  This should work for any .net language using Visual Studio.  I have it working for VB .net using VS2008 for several projects.  Here's how:

1. Go to the file system definitions in the setup project.  Right click in the folders section (left pane) and add special folder - System Folder.
2. Select the newly added System Folder in the left pane, and in the right hand pane, right click and select "add file."
3. Add the file msiexec.exe that is in your system32 folder (Most likely c:\windows\system32)
4. Go back to the left pane and drill down in the User's Programs Menu folder to the folder you want to hold the uninstall shortcut.  Select it.
5. In the right pane right click and select "create new shortcut."  In the dialog box, click on System Folder and then the msiexec.exe file.  Click OK and then rename the shortcut to whatever you want like "Uninstall MyProgram."
6. Right click on the new shortcut and select "properties window."
7. In the properties window, in the arguments variable type /x [ProductCode] (there is a space between the /x and [ProductCode]  You can use other switches instead of /x, if you want - check out the available switches for msiecec.exe.

That's it.  Now when you run the setup project it will add a shortcut to your user's program menu to uninstall the program.  One other comment, on the compile you will get a warning that msiexec.exe should be excluded because its source file is under Windows System File Protection.  Just ignore this warning.

Answer (score 0):

i too don't know how to find this elusive product code, but to answer your other question on removing the folder I found this document that may help you out

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/NET_Uninstaller.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get this product code from your **application setup project** in **properties window** of
your

***setup project***

. [Select project node in Solution Explorer and click F4 and copy the Product code.]
This looks similar to ... {21F66170-1C81-40E1-AB96-3303FF098425}

[image]